# How to copy different fill colors of a table column in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word 2010 document that has a table with 2 columns. They are both formatted except that the cells in the second column have no fill color yet. How do I copy only the fill colors of the cells of the first column to paste them into the cells of the second column, without changing other cell formattings? (There are too many cells to copy and paste individually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just verified that if you select a column with some shading set and insert a new column from the left side, then this new column inherits shading from the original column. On the basis of this behaviour the below solution worked for me:

- Select entire column with formatted values (without fill color),
- press Ctrl + C,
- then put cursor in the first cell of the column with color, press Ctrl + V.
- This will create a new column (as the first column).
- Then just remove last column (without color) and change order of column 1 and column 2 (select second column and drag on first column).

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a charm. The only change I made is that I cut instead of copy. And I had to repeat the cut&paste to switch back the location of the columns. Many thanks, endrju.